# How to solve this implicit equation? (use trial and error)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve this implicit equation and find $f$ When $Re$ is constant:  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}=2\log({Re.\sqrt{f})}- 0.8$$

I tried to make the equation simple By using:  $\sqrt{f}=t>0,Re=a$:
$$\frac{1}{t}=2\log({at})-0.8$$

$$0.8t=2t\log(at)-1$$

I can not find $t$ in this eqution. Should I draw graphs of $\frac{1}{t},2\log({at})-0.8$ and find intersection points for given "a" as question said with "trial and error method". But in general I don't like use this method for math questions. So is it possible to solve equation in other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved in terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): $$\frac{1}{2t}+\log\frac{1}{2t}=b:=\log\frac{a}{2}-0.4$$ or, for $x=1/(2t)$, we have $xe^x=e^b$, thus $x=W(e^b)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question you said for x=1/(2t) we have $xe^x=e^b$ but it is true if  the base of $log(\frac{1}{2t})$ is $e$ but here the base is 10 I think (It is a formula of physics and it doesn't say what is the logarithm base so I think It is 10)

Comment: @Soheil0098: Then we use $x=\frac{\ln 10}{2t}$ and get the same with $b=\ln\Big(\frac{a}{2}\ln 10\Big)-0.4\ln 10$.

Comment: Here:$$\frac{1}{2t}+\log\frac{1}{2t}=\log\frac{a}{2}-0.4$$

$$=\frac{1}{2t}+\frac{ln(\frac{1}{2t})}{ln10}=\frac{ln(\frac{a}{2})}{ln10}-0.4$$

$$=\frac{ln10}{2t}+ln(\frac{1}{2t})=ln(\frac{a}{2})-0.4×ln10 (consider\frac{ln10}{2t}=x)$$

$$\frac{xe^x}{ln10}=\frac{\frac{a}{2}}{10^{0.4}}$$
$$xe^x=\frac{a×ln10}{2×10^{0.4}}$$ Is this True?

Comment: I am not familiar with Lambert W function. If it is elementary to solve with Lambert Can you please show me how it should be solved?

Comment: @Soheil0098: Yes, your derivation is correct. The Lambert function is *not* elementary, and there's *no* elementary solution. (BTW, for future: use `\ln`, not just `ln`, and similarly `\log`, `\sin`, etc.)